# Discern infinite value from array of floats

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting, infinity

I'm using the function [scipy.optimize.curve_fit](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html) to fit some data. If the fit converges normally, `curve_fit` will return two arrays `popt` and `pcov` that will look something like this for a function of two parameters:

```
print popt
[  2.97591488e-03   3.08947359e+01]
print pcov
[[  2.44224139e-06  -1.67832708e-02]
 [ -1.67832708e-02   1.16808802e+02]]
```

The issue is that occasionally the function will fail to obtain a valid `pcov` resulting in:

```
print pcov
inf
```

I need to be able to tell when `pcov` is a "valid" list/array of floats and when it's an `inf` "invalid" value.

I've tried:

```
if np.isfinite(np.array(pcov).any()):
    print 'valid'
else:
    print 'invalid'
```

but this does not give good results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, just a temporary mind block from 11+ hours of writing code. The correct way is:

```
if np.isfinite(pcov).all():
    print 'valid'
else:
    print 'invalid'
```